# How to extract rows present only once by column via commandline

Tags: terminal, uniq

I have a space separated file as shown below:

```
D2ABMACXX:5:1101:10000:93632_1:N:0 c111 12462 6
D2ABMACXX:5:1101:10004:54586_1:N:0 c6753 3473 1
D2ABMACXX:5:1101:10004:54586_2:N:0 c7000 5726 1
D2ABMACXX:5:1101:10006:56411_1:N:0 c4282 877 42
D2ABMACXX:5:1101:10006:56411_2:N:0 c5703 240 6
D2ABMACXX:5:1101:10013:29259_2:N:0 c6008 384 11
```

I would need to extract rows that are present only once based on the text before "_" in column 1.  The sample output should look like below:

```
##required output format###
D2ABMACXX:5:1101:10000:93632_1:N:0 c111 12462 6
D2ABMACXX:5:1101:10013:29259_2:N:0 c6008 384 11
```

I have a complicated way of doing this but loosing original information:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$1}' | sed 's/_1//g; s/_2//g' | uniq -f 3 -u
```

Could anyone suggest an optimal way of doing this on a huge text file ~10Gb getting the output in the same format as that of input as shown in the required output format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing all with `awk`, for example:

```
awk -F'_' '{ uniqs[$1] = $0; count[$1]++ } END { for (uniq in uniqs) if ( count[uniq] == 1 ) print uniqs[uniq] }' file.txt
```